# SSO experience with SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, sfauthenticationsession

In the [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/SFAuthenticationSession) description it's written that

The two cases where you would use SFAuthenticationSession are:

> Logging in to a third party's service using an authentication protocol
>   (e.g. OAuth). This option works well for social network applications.
>
> Providing a single sign-on (SSO) experience for applications. This
>   option works well for enterprise companies that have many applications
>   installed on the same device.

I wanted to implement the second scenario. I have different apps and used the SFSafariViewController to implement a SSO. The problem is that in my tests the cookies was not shared between the different apps. I logg in in one app and then when I try to log-in in another app with the same login URL, I have to write my credentials again, even if the session is still active in the first app. Is that the normal behavior? How I am supposed to implement a SSO experience if the cookies are not shared between my apps?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 11 SFSafariViewController no longer shares cookies. You should probably be looking into SFAuthenticationSession instead for OAuth SSO scenarios.